# How to add images as thumbnail in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I am creating image viewer, similar to windows image viewer in SWT, I want to add images from one directory  in thumbnail view while clicking in one image, the image should be enlarged.

What to use for this (Image Registry or Image Descriptor)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [Gallery](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/gallery/gallery.php). That is a sub-project of Nebula, which provides SWT widgets.